Upper and lower contour sets of a convex function?
First let me present an observation. Suppose $f$ is a convex function. Suppose $f(x)<f(y)$. Then for any $t>0$, we must have $f(y+t(y-x))\geqslant f(y)$. The proof is as follows. Suppose instead $f(y+t(y-x))<f(y)$, then both $x$ and $y+t(y-x)$ is in the (strict) lower contour set of $y$. Because $f$ is convex, the lower contour set is convex. Note that $y$ is a convex combination of $x$ and $y+t(y-x)$, then $y$ is in its own strict lower contour set, which is impossible.
I feel that the above conclusion should be strengthened to $f(y+t(y-x))>f(y)$ (I checked constant function, quadratic function, and V-shape function). But my above proof does not work because a point belonging to its own weakly lower contour set does not lead to a contradiction. Is my conjecture correct? If so, how to prove it?

If $f(y+t(y-x)=f(y)$ then, since $y$ is a convex combination of $x$ and $y+t(y-x)$, we would have $f(y)\le f(x)$,a contradiction.
[If $y=sx+(1-s) (y+t(y-x))$ where $0\le s \le1$ then $f(y) \leq s f(x)+(1-s)f(y+t(y-x))=sf(x)+(1-s)f(y)$ which gives $f(y) \le f(x)$].

in the last line, how do you get "=" in $s f(x)+(1-s)f(y+t(y-x))=sf(x)+(1-s)f(y)$ and "$\le$" in $f(y) \le f(x)$?

@GBmath '=' in the last line because of line 1 in my answer. Last step is simple algebra.
